# problem with scrolling a list created with input type radio (JavaScript )

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to activate the list when scrolling, but the problem is that when I scroll up the lower list is activated, not the upper one. In short when I want to scroll up, it scrolls down. How can I solve it?

also you can check this link to see how it currently works.
https://vegatekhub.com/discovery-2/

```js
let amount = 0;
let current = 1;
let max = 4;

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  amount++;
  if (amount >= 50) {
    amount = 0;
    document.getElementById('r' + current).checked = false;
    //If you reach the last radio element you reset the counter
    if (current == max)
      current = 1;
    else
      current += 1;
    document.getElementById('r' + current).checked = true;

  }
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r2">
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r3">
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r4">

<div class="controls">
  <label for="r1"><span></span>LAB & Process Development</label>
  <label for="r2"><span></span>Quality & Regulatory</label>
  <label for="r3"><span></span>Engineering & Project Management</label>
  <label for="r4"><span></span>EHS</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to show a demonstration of the problem. The code you've shown does not display the behaviour you describe.

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work here but i put the link down below  for you to check it there     https://vegatekhub.com/discovery-2/